# Activate test coverage for python code on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, pytest-cov

I'm trying to create a `.gilab-ci.yml` step to activate the gitlab's test coverage with pytest + pytest-cov.

### Current unsuccessful snippet

I've tried:

```yaml
.only-default: &only-default
  only:
    - merge_requests

stages:
  - test

test-py:
  stage: test
  image: "python:3.8"
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python -m pytest -vvv  src --cov-report xml --cov=src
  artifacts:
    reports:
      cobertura: coverage.xml
```

Among other packages used for my project, the `requirements.txt` file contains pytest and pytest-cov.

The associated pipeline outputted:

```
Uploading artifacts...
coverage.xml: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "cobertura" to coordinator... ok  id=858390324 responseStatus=201 Created token=6uBetoBX
```

But I'm unable to see the new feature in my MR.

Does anyone have a working solution to activate the option ?

### Reference page

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html

Comment: looks like the argument you pass to pytest should be `--cov-report xml:coverage.xml` - you didn't specify a filename. Or is coverage.xml the default?

Comment: I think I found the real problem; the gitlab documentation example uses coverage.py to convert the report to use full relative paths. The information isn’t displayed without the conversion. So I don't think it's possible to use just pytest for this.

Comment: There is a python example section in their docs that should be helpful: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html#python-example

Answer (score 2):

Solution to this question can be found in the issue in the gitlab repo:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/285086

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html) states that coverage.py is needed to convert the report to use full relative paths. The information isn’t displayed without the conversion.

So in your example, instead of:

```
- python -m pytest -vvv  src --cov-report xml --cov=src
```

Do:

```
- python -m pytest -vvv  src --cov=src
- coverage xml -o coverage.xml
```